# How to install SeDuMi for YALMIP matlab after downloaded?

Tags: matlab

Dear All the Greatest Lords,

My complicated semi numerical processing project demanded I should exploit some mysterious power of conic optimization of the toolbox sedumi. It is a magic computation tool written by one of the world's most famous outstanding achieved mathematician, computer scientist and engineer Jos F. Sturm from the world-renowned McMaster University. That hapless God created creature unfortunately passed away at the very beginning of this millennium due to vicious disease or tragic accident I guess. But all the community of mathematics and computation will memorize him and his masterpiece the will be 
hornored by all the ones living today. I was one among those who are lucky enough to enjoy his precious legacy. But a last hinder seems to stand between me and the sharing of it. I've googled around to get no implication of how to install it and be utilized by the matlaB or (YALMIP).

Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you try unzipping it and adding it to the matlab search path? When toolboxes don't come with installation instructions, they typically don't need an installation. Use `addpath(genpath('c:\example_toolbox'))` to add a directory including all subdirectories.

Comment: Hmm. "+1" for entertainment value or flag as "unclear what you're asking"? Maybe both?

Comment: You say "for entertainment"? No, not a game. Not for entertainment use . It's just a program for scientific research or appreciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download from github https://github.com/sqlp/sedumi (since that distribution has recent bug fixes and precompiled binaries), unzip, addpath(genpath('c:...sedumidirectory')) in MATLAB.

If you want to use YALMIP to interface SeDuMi, download from http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/, unzip, addpath(genpath('c:...yalmipdirectory')).

Study examples on the YALMIP Wiki. Questions are best asked on the YALMIP forum https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/yalmip

/johan (YALMIP developer, sedumi co-maintainer)